# Run python script from Gnome desktop

Tags: python

I'm running CentOS on a virtual machine and am just starting to mess with python. I'm relatively new to Linux and I'm trying to figure out how to execute a python script with a double click on the .py file. The file contains only:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Hello World!")
```

I used `chmod +x file.py` to make it executable and it's now on my desktop. However upon double click it still opens the file in gedit instead of executing it as a script.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of running scripts in *NIX environment is to open a terminal and run `python path/to/script.py <arguments>` as opposed to double clicking. Making it executable simple means it can be run with `./` like so `./path/to/script.py`. An idiomatic example of this is Django's manage script: `./manage.py runserver` for instance.

It's most likely possible to run a script by double clicking it but it would probably require more work than it would be worth. Especially since once you become accustomed to Linux you will be more used to using the terminal anyway.

Comment: My mistake, I was under the impression this was a common thing to do, since I remember when I wrote python in windows it would automatically bind the files to execute on click.

Comment: It happens. I'm sure I thought the same thing when I first switched to Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't run a python script like that without some logic that creates a UI or a change in the desktop environment. To run a simple script like this you need to use the terminal with `python myfile.py`

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, it is common to run scripts from the command line instead by double clicking.

But if you really want to, you can create a Desktop launcher, as explained in [this post on *Ask Ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to utilize the gui is by installing software's like spyder. You have to right click and select open with spyder. Or you can associate the py files to spyder as default.  This will open in spyder by double clicking and then just press green run button on top toolbar of spyder. Spyder is just an example of running python without terminal.  You have so many other software's like this.